# not getting the outpout of following code

Tags: javascript

the following code converts an encoded message by adding 4 to its character's ASCII values eg.A-->D,M-->p,the code is case sensitive.

```
    var convertCode = function (sample) {
        var newArray = sample.split(""); //converting string to array//
        var x = newArray.length;
        var testArray = [];
        var resultArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            testArray.push(newArray[i].charCodeAt(0)); //conversion of characters to ASCII values//
            testArray[i] = testArray[i] + 4; //ADD 4 to ASCII values

            if (testArray[i] > 90 && testArray[i] <= 94) { //condition to keep uppercase alphabets within range//
                testArray[i] = testArray[i] - 90 + 65;
            } else if (testArray[i] > 122 && testArray[i] <= 126) { //condition to keep lowercase alphabets within range//
                testArray[i] = testArray[i] - 122 + 97;
            }

            resultArray.push(string.fromCharCode(testArray[i]));
            //converting the new Ascii values back to string//
        }
        resultArray.join(); //conversion of array back to string//
        alert(resultArray);
    };
    convertCode("ABCDE");
```

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(testArray[i])` - `String` not `string`

Comment: Your browser console have an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: string is not defined`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e9fnhccg/2/

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have used `string` which is treated as variable, upon running the program you will get `string is not defined`, actually you are looking for 'String' class instead of variable.

```
resultArray.push(String.fromCharCode(testArray[i]));
```

instead of

```
resultArray.push(string.fromCharCode(testArray[i]));
```

Also, add `3` instead of `4` to turn `A` into `D`

```
testArray[i] = testArray[i] + 4;
```